# ABNewPersonViewController in a subview

Tags: ios, ipad, addressbook

I am writing an iPad app that requires the user to enter names and addresses and would like to use ABNewPersonViewController as the interface.  The documentation says that this view controller should only be used from within a navigation controller.  Is there anyway I can use just the ABNewPersonViewController in a subview (with a navigation controller) without it taking over my whole screen?  I assume I can do this easily enough in a popover but I would prefer to have it integrated into my interface...  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after much looking into this, it does not see that there is any way to use the address book UIs in a subview but they do work quite well in a popover view.  However, this popover needs to be exactly 320x460 pixels or some other number with the same aspect ratio for the "add photo" to work correctly (otherwise the photo is stretched).  In the popover's view controller viewDidLoad method I added:

```
self.picker = [[[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.picker] autorelease];
self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

This seems to work fine.  Let me know if you know of something better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider presenting your `UINavigationViewController` by `presentModalViewController:animated:` and change `modalViewPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`.

See the reference : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html